# How to access const(without export const variable) variable in my app.module and access it from children components in angular?

Tags: angular

app.module.ts
const test: boolean = false; // i want to access this variable to another component.
//note: there is no export variable of test.

test.component.ts file
here i want to access the const test varaible inside test component.

Please let me know how to access

Comment: You can't really? You'd need to specifically expose this to other components (through a service or an Input).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#using-an-injectiontoken-object), but I'm not pretty sure if it is what are you looking for

```
//your module:

const test:boolean=false
@NgModule({
  imports:      [... ],
  declarations: [ ... ],
  providers: [{ provide: "TEST", useValue: test }],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})

//your component
constructor(@Inject("TEST") private config: string) {
    this.name = config?"test is true":"test is false";
}
```

(*)Usually you use uppercase to use value as provider, but you can use any string